# Почему 'я хочу серьезных отношений'?

Tags: родительный-падеж

Почему в предложении 'я хочу серьезных отношений' объект находится в родительном падеже?

Comment: А почему вы считаете что он не должен находиться в родительном падеже?

Comment: @shabunc, потому что "хочу *кого? что?*"? Пример: хочу облако. Вот только с первым склонением тоже как-то не получается (хочу страну, хочу машину).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rosenthal et al., "Пунктуация и управление в русском языке":

> **хотеть** *чего* и (при конкретизации объекта) *что*.
>
> *— Хочешь золота али жемчугу? (Лермонтов).*
>
> *— Хочу только свою книгу.*

This means that verbs like *хотеть*, *требовать*, *ждать* etc. require genitive when the object is indefinite and accusative when the object is definite (already mentioned in context).

This is probably the closest thing Russian has to definite / indefinite distinction most other Indo-European languages mandatorily express with articles and postfixes.

*Хочу чаю* means "I want some tea" and *хочу чай* means "I want the tea" (some specific cup of tea which has been mentioned earlier).

In your example, this would mean "I want **a** serious relationship", meaning "one of those serious relationships people keep talking about".

This is not some particular relationship, this is just a concept being introduced into the context, hence the "a" in the English phrase and the genitive in the Russian one.

Answer (score 0):

Надо еще добавить, что управление с винительным падежом после глагола *хотеть* используется довольно редко и во многих случаях звучит просторечно или по-детски. Например, как в известном фильме "Мимино" - "Ларису Ивановну хочу!" (вместо "Позовите пожалуйста к телефону Л.И."). Или "хочу конфету" в детской речи. Взрослый обычно перефразирует эту фразу в "хочу съесть конфету".

Невозможно и использовать родительный падеж в данном случае ("Ларисы Ивановны хочу"). Родительный падеж звучит хорошо только с неисчисляемыми (хочу воды - означает хочу некоторое количество воды) или абстрактными существительными (хочу уважения, не хочу насилия), но не с исчисляемыми (хочу книги).